# Cypress conditional testing code suggestions

Tags: javascript, cypress

I cant figure out how to automate if & else using Cypress. I am new to Cypress & JS and trying to work this out.

I have questions page, sometimes its 3 and sometimes its 4. Not consistent. I simply want to handle case where cypress click on No, if its finds that 4 "NO" button. Also CTA button in the end changes, if the 4th question is present the text of CTA changes.

The problem with "Should" in Cypress is that it asserts and then fails. I want something like IsDisplayed in selenium.

I know conditional testing is not recommended, but I dont have an option now. Please help me with this.

this is my code:

```
    //cy.get(`button[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).then($a => {
    cy.get('div span.MultiScreenForm__content').then($a => {
      if ($a.attr('name', `[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).length > 0) {
        cy.log('Cosmetic Damage Button does exist: ==>');
        cy.get(`button[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).click();
      } else {
        cy.log('Cosmetic Damage Button does not exist, do Nothing');
      }
    });
  }
```

[image: DOM Image]

Comment: What output your code is giving ?

Comment: @KaranSharma It fails when the button doesnt exist. So I am not sure if the code is working fine. It goes into if condition loop even when the button doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2):

> I know conditional testing is not recommended, but I dont have an option now.

Yes, you do have an option. I apologize up front, this is not a quick, easy answer. Conditional testing in cypress can be tricky, however, when you do understand it, your tests will be better for it. You do have a better option and I'm going to try my best to explain it, so here goes.

For situations like this, you have to adjust the way that you approach the problem. At the moment, you're basing your condition on the UI element which, [as Cypress documentation states](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-DOM-is-unstable), will lead to exploding kittens. No one wants exploding kittens. What you want to do instead is change the source of truth your condition is based on from using the UI element to basing your condition on something more stable, like server response.

*For me, personally, this was incredibly difficult to wrap my brain around how to actually do this in practice*, so I'll try my best to explain.

So, currently, you're doing something like:

- Request is made (#of questions) and page loads and view is set based on response.
- If UI element is on page (4th question), then test button

What you want instead is:

- Request is made (how many questions?)
- Capture response from request with `cy.route("someAlias")` and `cy.wait('@someAlias')`
- Your response from the server is the information that your UI elements are building themselves from. **Base your condition on this instead.** (see [Routes & Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Routes))

So your condition would be something like:

`if questions returned in response > 3 then test button`.

The theory here is, your server is a solid source of truth which has all the info you need, right up front. The DOM (UI elements) is not because it does not have all of the info you need up front and there is no guarantee at the time of your condition that it will have resolved the stuff you need in order to proceed.

If your server responds with more than 3 questions, there should be a button there. Switching the logic here makes your test more stable and you're actually testing the thing that you want to test. *When you've got more than 3 questions, you should have a button*. **Not** if there are more than three UI elements, then you should have a button. *There is no guarantee that your button will have resolved by the time your condition is met for the UI elements.* Your server response should be your source of truth, not the UI elements.

I don't know the logic that you have that makes the request so my answer isn't exact, however, let's assume that on page load, there is a request to `/questions` that responds with the questions that you're talking about (3 or 4). Your code would then look something like this:

```
// setup the route to wait for
cy.server();
cy.route("/questions").as("questions");
// do whatever you do that sends that request
cy.visit("/pageOfQuestions");
// wait for request and grab response using route alias
cy.wait("@questions").then(function(xhr) {
  // find your path (I'm guessing here) to the info you need and test condition
  // the condition and the path to the info will vary based on what your response 
  // actually contains
  if(xhr.response.questions.length > 3) {
    // test your button-y stuff here
    cy.get(`button[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).click();
  } else {
    cy.log("nothing to test");
}
```

The difference is when you base your condition (source of truth) on the UI elements, the DOM does not always resolve itself in the manner you expect. When you reach the condition (in this case the question UI elements), other things still haven't resolved themselves (button UI elements). You have to wait for two elements to align in the DOM -> Your source of truth (condition) and the UI element you want to test (button). Often, one hasn't loaded when the other has and you cannot rely on them loading consistently which is why cypress recommends never basing conditions on UI elements, unless you like exploding kittens.

Explained differently, let's say the DOM has 10 resources to load. You're saying to cypress:
`if resource #7 looks like this then play with resource #1`

Cypress goes and waits for resource 7. When it's ready it checks that the condition is met and then tries to play with resource 1... which the DOM possibly hasn't resolved yet. And actually, sometimes it could be loaded but you can never guarantee that it will be which will lead to flaky tests.

*When you base your source of truth on the server response, you're only waiting for and testing the one UI element* and the cypress built-in time outs can successfully wait for that one element to load without depending on another. `On page load, did the server give us more than 4 things? Then play with UI element`

If there's anything I can clarify, just ask.

Reference:

- [Conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-DOM-is-unstable)
- [Routes and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Routes)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your description and the snipped you provided is that `[name="cosmeticDamage"]` is always there for several elements, so I'm not really sure how does `.length` valorizes `[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`, which could mean your condition is always true.

I would recommend to go for `find`, as it filters matching descendent DOM elements:

```
    cy.get('div span.MultiScreenForm__content').then($form => {
        if ($form.find(`[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).is(':visible')) {
            cy.get(`button[name="cosmeticDamage"][value="${cosmetic}"]`).click();        
        } else {
            cy.log('Cosmetic Damage Button does not exist, do Nothing');
        }
    });
```